# Query model with array in mongodb

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new in node and MongoDB.

I am trying to query a model with an array.

The array looks like this

```
 var grArr =  [ '5aabc39a3d88101e4b52c861', '5ac3a1fe83d45353bc6a995c' ]
```

And the query is

```
Group.find().where({ _id: { $in: grArr }}).exec(function(err,gdoc){
      if(err)
      {
         callback({err:err,message:"Error looking up company"});
      }
      else
      {
         console.log(gdoc.companies); //Gives undefined
         callback(null,gdoc.companies);
      }
});
```

The query returns `undefined`.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: find query returns array. So here `gdoc` is an array you either need to loop over the `gdoc` and console the values or console `gdoc[0].companies`

Comment: With MongoDB it's easiest to first use queries in the console to see whether or not they work, you don't have to run anything and stdout/stderr is directly there

Comment: @Anthony Is there any other way where it will return all the ids but not in array. Thank yoi.

Comment: Could you explain what you really need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is 2 ways to perform a query with mongoose, and it seems to me that you're mixing both of them.

- [Find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html) should be called with your query as parameter:

And you get something like

```
Group.find({ _id: { $in: grArr }}, function(err,gdoc){
      if(err) {
         callback({err: err, message:"Error looking up company"});
      }
      else {
         console.log(gdoc); //Should print all the matching documents since gdoc is an array
         callback(null, gdoc.map(doc => doc.companies); //returns every companies of every document
      }
});
```

- The [Query API](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/query.html) of mongoose

This time you can call Find with no parameters and chain the where statement like this

```
Group.find({}).where('_id').in(grArr).exec(callback)
```

Comment: Yes, I was mixing both. It works great. I got the ids in array in this way -- `var companies = [].concat(...gdoc.map(doc => doc.companies));`

Answer (score 0):

`find()` passed array to the callback function. See documentation https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

`gdoc` is array. Edit your code like this:

```
...
callback(null, gdoc[0].companies);
...
```

Comment: If I have 2 elements in an array then it would be gdoc[0] and gdoc[1]. Any other way to avoid to run a loop of gdoc.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra you are going to have to loop over them anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Group.find({ _id: { $in:arr }).lean().exec().then((result) => {

}, (err) => {

});
```